# Unnest only one duplicate value per row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table -

```
ID    A1     A2     A3     A4     A5      A6
1    324    243    3432   23423  342     342
2    342    242    4345   23423  324     342
```

I can unnest this table to give me counts of all numbers like so -

```
324     2
243     1
3432    1
23423   1
342     3
242     1
4345    1
23423   1
```

But how do I get it to count numbers in the same row only 1 time. For example, this is the output I am expecting -

```
324     2
243     1
3432    1
23423   1
342     2 
242     1
4345    1
23423   1
```

`342` is `2` because -

1) It is in the first row.

2) It appears 2 times in the second row, but I only want to count it once.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `count(distinct)`:

```
select v.a, count(distinct t.id)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (a1), (a2), (a3), (a4), (a5), (a6)
     ) v(a)
group by v.a;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a5b076e35e25c5a0c49c424deee65828) is a db<>fiddle.